# Juju deploy services to two machines

Tags: juju, services

Hello i want to know if i'm doing it right- I install juju-gui on the 0 machine after that i want to install openstack-dashboard and a few other services to machine 2 and when i do it they go - pending mode. I can login with juju ssh 2 to the other computer but the services are pending. What should i do? Thanks

Comment: Be sure to mark answers as accepted if they answered your question, or at the very least upvote it if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the machine is up but the services get stuck in pending you will want to view the logs for hints as to why they are stuck.

You can find the logs in `/var/log/juju` on the machine.

You will also find some more information on debugging hooks here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/developer-debugging

Comment: All services are started but there is an 500 Internal Server Error is it possible that some services use the same port as other and that is the reason?